# Firefox display-table-cell not showing border-right and bottom

Tags: css, tablecell

Firefox `display-table-cell` not showing `border-right` and `border-bottom`!

[image]

**The Code:**

```css
.slides {
  display: table;
}
.proImgSection, .profileInfo {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.profileInfo {
  border: 1px solid #5d5d5d;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slides">
  <div class="proImgSection">
    <img src="img/li-europan_img.jpg">
  </div> <!--  .proImgSection -->
  <div class="profileInfo">
    <div class="profileInner">
      <span class="u_name"><span class="greenTxt">Li Europan </span></span>
      <p>Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular </p>
    </div> <!--  .profileInner -->
  </div> <!--  .img -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Given your answer, it seems it's just that the table overflows a container with `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem by using a [CSS Table](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp) and the [calc() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

```
.slides {
  display: table;
  width: calc(100% - 1px);
}
```

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box`